# Access Expression/VBA for Matching Entry with Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am not very good at VBA in access. I have what I think should be a reasonably simple task: when a zip code is entered in a combo box, I would like to verify that the County (on the same table with Zip codes) of that zip is the same as the county entered in an earlier part of the form - or, if no county was entered, for the zip to populate that field with a County.

In other words, I don't want to simply populate a given field when data is entered into another, but to verify the data entered in two separate fields are consistent with two columns in a table (and then to act accordingly).

I have a County combo box which is related to a table with a list of counties; then I have a zip combo box which is related to a table with Zip Code, Town, County (3 columns).

I hope this makes sense; thanks very much for any help..

Here is my meager attempt:

```
Private Sub zip_AfterUpdate()
If Me![County] <> Me![Zip].Column(2) Then 
MsgBox "County selected does not match zip code."
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Please read that link and make sure that the code you post in your question is **minimal** (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), **complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **verifiable** (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). This will help the Stack Overflow community by clarifying the problem.

Comment: Your code should work to verify the county.  (You may need an END IF to close your IF statement).  For the other part, if the me!County is null, then just assign me!County = me!Zip.column(2).

Comment: Perhaps you should use cascading combobox for the zip codes. Select county then zip code list is restricted to only zip codes in that county.

Comment: Thanks geeFlo and June7; both really good suggestions!